# Find the coordinates of the points $A$ and $B$ on the lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively such that $\vec{AB}$ is perpendicular to $l_1$ and $l_2$

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

The vector $l_1$ is given as
$$
l_1 : \mathbf{r} =  
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-3\\-4\\6
\end{matrix}
\right)\; + \lambda 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-3\\-4\\6
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and $l_2$ as
$$
l_2: \frac{x-4}{-3}=\frac{y+7}{4}=-(z+3)
$$

So far I've gotten an equation for each $(x,y,z)$ of $l_1$ and $l_2$ and then multiplied them to get a scalar product however I'm having issues finding the values of $\lambda$ and $\nu$ (Cartesian multiplier of $l_2$) through the simultaneous equations of finding the scalar product (when it's equal to $0$).

My approach, at least so far has given,
$$
\vec{OB} = \left(\begin{matrix}
4\\
-7\\
-3
\end{matrix}\right)+\nu
\left(\begin{matrix}
-3\\
4\\
-1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$ 
$$
\vec{AB} = \vec{OB}-\vec{AB}
$$
Therefore
$$
\vec{AB} = \left(\begin{matrix}
1\\
3\\
9
\end{matrix}\right)+
\left(\begin{matrix}
-3\nu - 3\lambda\\
4\nu - 2\lambda\\
-\nu + 2\lambda
\end{matrix}\right)
$$ 
$$
x = 1 -3\nu - 3 \lambda,\; y = -3 + 4\nu - 2\lambda, \; z=-9+\nu + 2\lambda
$$
Then solving for the two dot products,
$$
\vec{AB} \; \cdot \; l_1, \; \vec{AB} \; \cdot \; l_2
$$
I get
$$
26\nu^2-17\lambda^2 = 0
$$
Which I have no idea how to solve. The response was too long for the comment section.

Comment: Your method is right. What issue do you find?

Comment: Couldn't simplify further than having two composite quadratics, perhaps I made an arithmetic mistake but I don't see it after going through many times.

Comment: There should not be any quadratic terms. Can you show some detail of your steps?

Comment: @Yuta I have edited my answer.

Comment: Since $AB\perp l_1$ and $AB\perp l_2$, dot products should be considered instead.

Comment: Oh sorry that's what I did, I was just confusing myself with @Bernard 's answer.

Comment: You must take the dot product of $\vec{AB}$ with the DIRECTIONS of the two lines, not with vectors $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$. In addition, your result for $\vec{AB}$ looks wrong: you should check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A (slightly) different approach*:

$l_2$ is defined as the intersection of the planes $x-3z=7$ and $y+4z=-19$, with normal vectors $\vec n=(1,0,-3)$ and $\vec n'=(0,1,4)$ respectively. Therefore, a directing vector of $l_2$ is the cross-product $\vec u_2=\vec n\times\vec n'$.

Let $\vec u_1=(-3,-4,6)$ the given directing vector of $l_1$. A directing vector of the common perpendicular of $l_1$ and $l_2$ is the cross-product
$$\vec v=\vec u_1\times\vec u_2. $$
Thus, to find points $A$ on $l_1$  and $B$ on $l_2$ so that the line $(AB)$ is perpendicular to $l_1$ and $l_2$, we have to find a point $A$ (given by the parametric equation) and $t$ so  the point
$$B=A+t\vec v= A+t(\vec u_1\times\vec u_2)$$
satisfies the equations of line $l_2$.

Comment: @John Miller: Where did you find 3 equations and  7 variables? You should obtain the two equations which  define $l_2$ and  two unknowns, $\lambda$ and $t$.

Comment: sorry I never wrote it on paper as I was in the car but I have solved the question thank you.